# How to build a complex sql query?

Tags: sql, laravel

[Database design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbb46.png)

I want to get records from the product_spec_data table that are associated with products whose category_id is 5.

Please help me make a query to the database...

Comment: What have you tried? Are the relationships set in your models? It really does not look like a "complex query... " just a simple `hasManyThrough` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @gert-b Thank you for the hint, I will try to implement it now.

Comment: @gert-b, Can you show an example? 

What should it look like?

Here I get a collection of products: $category->products ().
how do I make it so that I get only product Spec Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the relationship are clearly laid out, a simple join across tables would works.

```
SELECT psd.*
FROM product_spec_data psd
INNER JOIN product_spec_values psv ON psd.id = psv.product_spec_data_id
INNER JOIN products prod ON psv.product_id = prod.id
INNER JOIN categories cat ON prod.category_id = cat.id
-- with category id = 5
WHERE cat.id = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by complex query. I guess your question is not complete. I think the query for your question (if it is T-SQL) will be as follows

```
select d.* 
from product_spec_data d
left outer join product_spec_values v on d.id=v.product_spec_data_id
left outer join products p on v.product_id=p.id
where p.category_id=5
```

(I think in MySQL also above syntax will remain same, you may remove [outer] clause in MySQL)